# Convert Javascript number to two decimal places

Tags: javascript

I know there have been many threads on this topic but none seem to answer my question directly. I want to convert a number to two decimal places no matter the length. So 0.5 should turn into 0.50, and 5.3145 should go to 5.31. Most importantly, I also need to keep the number as a number datatype. I know toFixed(2) will create two decimal places, but this also turns the number into a string. If I wrap the toFixed(2) with a parseInt function (e.g. parseInt(amount.toFixed(2))) then 0.5 seems to be converted to "0.50", and then back to 0.5 with out the trailing zero. Adding a second layer of parentheses doesn't solve the problem either. Any ideas?? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Numbers do NOT have trailing zeros so if you need the trailing zero, you need to have a string.

Comment: This can not be done and keep the datatype. You would have to convert it to a string because numbers can not have trailing 0s.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is impossible to do. Numbers do not have trailing zeros. There are no significant digits. So when you need the trailing zero, you need to convert it to a string with toFixed().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trailing zeros for mathematical computations - so if you are just looking to display it - keep it a string and use the toFixed(2) then when you need to do computations on it - convert with parseFloat